# Laravel multiple relations, save either one or the other

Tags: php, laravel, relation

So I am wondering about the best approach for this issue. I have an appointments table and two relations, a `contact` relation and a `company` relation. In my `appointments.create` form, I want to be able to either select a contact, or a company, not both. I was thinking of two approaches but I hope there is a better way to accomplish this.

1. I can enter a question in my form, asking if the user wants to add a contact or a company, and if they select `contact`, I will display a contact dropdown, and the same for when the user selects `company`. In my `appointments` table I will have two fields, a `contact_id` and a `company_id`. I save whichever the user selected and set the other to either 0 or null. Then in my controller I select which was filled, and then grab the correct relation.
2. I can use the same field in my database for both, for example `relation_id` and then add another field to which I can save the text `contact` or `company`, and based on that I grab the correct relation in my views.

But both of these solutions seem like non solutions to me, and I am hoping there is a better way to achieve this, and since I have struggled with this a lot in the past as well, I thought it would be good to ask it here since I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: The first solution makes sense to me. Unless you want to extend the functionality to a third (or more) relation type in the future.

Comment: Yeah so I am on the right track then, I will have to sleep on this and see what makes the most sense to me and maybe hopefully the first solution will make sense to me also :)

Comment: Why do you think it would be bad?

Comment: It just seems... amateuristic to me. But having slept a night over it, I do think this is the way to go. It's indeed better to keep these fields seperated in the database. And I won't need to add a third relation type in the future